# How to show that if a set $S \subseteq \mathbb R$ is bounded below, then it has an infimum?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose that $S \subseteq \mathbb R$ and that $S$ is bounded below. Show that $S$ must have an infimum.

The way I approached the problem was by making a set $\dot S = \{-s : s \in S\}$. It must be the case that $\dot S$ is bounded above. Thus, by the supremum property of $\mathbb R$, there must be a $u$ such that $u = sup \ \dot S$. How can I show that $-u$ must be the infimum of $S$?

Comment: That depends on how you define $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Assume $-u$ isn't the infimum, but there exists a $-v>-u$ with $-v$ a lower bound.  What does that say about $v$ and $\dot S$?